# Create new group using telegram bot API

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How can I create new groups using a bot in Telegram?

As far as I know a bot cannot do this itself, so is it possible to implement a bot as a regular **user**? How?

**Update :**
This is what I want http://t.me/polyglossia

Comment: Use [telegram-cli](https://valtman.name/telegram-cli)

Comment: Bots cannot be human users :) but they can be admins.

Comment: @naser.sadeghi But i knew people who has done this, just I can't access them for now

Comment: @ShahinSorkh Telegram says this is not possible. And I prefer to believe.

Comment: @mymedia pretty good idea. Thanks!

Comment: @naser.sadeghi check the link I've added, that's what I'm talking about

Comment: @ShahinSorkh Shahin I checked that link. In this robot the groups are made before and the bot guids you to them when you choose one of the groups. As I saw the groups are fixed and made before by human users and just added to the bot as a link and the bot(s) is(are) one of the admins of those groups.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi bot is the creator, check the groups' creator buddy

Comment: @ShahinSorkh How do you say that??? I mean what is the sign that the bot is the creator???

Comment: @ShahinSorkh If you say that based on the star sign next to the names in members area, I have to say that star stands for administrator. You'd better make a group and add some people to it yourself, then add a robot to it as an admin then you will see that other users will see that star sign next to your name and the bot's. In the link you mentioned the bot is administrator as well, not the creator

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi ik that :| use unofficial Telegram apps like plus, also the creator has blue star while other admins have gray

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi leave the groups, check the profile, that's a bot without bot suffix in username and it has a mobile number placeholder and doesn't have an about section

Comment: hello guys, how did you solve the problem? I also need the API to create group chat on telegram, is there any solutions?

Answer (score 6):

As I know this is impossible according to the latest telegram bot api and its documentation that can be find [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

> Bots cannot create channels, groups and super groups they can only be
>   added to groups or channel as administrator manually by human users.

Comment: But i knew people who has done this, just I can't access them for now

Comment: probably too late. but the people that does this, don't use **Telegram Bot API**. they use Telegram API that uses the user credentials and you have to get your access key from telegram website then you can program  your automation on it. **but** not as a bot!

Answer (score 1):

I myself don't use unofficial telegram apps and I have to say that they don't use the telegram bot API they use **the Telegram API (which is used to make your own customized telegram app).**

Because you have to implement every telegram feature yourself when developing such an app, It can be possible to make bots able to create groups or channels. If you have the enough programming knowledge to create your own you can do it.

Comment: Did it help you??