# Create new group in telegram

Tags: telegram

Like [Create new group using telegram bot API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897683/), but not by API -- how to create new group in telegram myself?

https://telegram.org/faq#q-how-do-i-create-a-group says:

> Click the menu button in the top left corner > ‘New Group’.

but looks to me the faq is outdated, as it is no longer working:

1. Open Telegram.
2. Click ☰.
3. Click New Group.
4. Type a name for the group.

Then, I can do nothing but "Cancel" -- The “Next” is always grayed out.

Anybody knows? thx.

Comment: in android or ios?

Comment: android _and_ telegram web

Comment: use this site: https://www.wikihow.com/Start-a-Telegram-Group-on-Android for me its done in android

Comment: Yeah, saw that, but I don't have any people in my contacts list, just the bot I created. However, I'm not able to create group with that bot either.

Comment: You have to invite at last one more user to continue

Comment: Nothing to do with programming

Comment: gotya, @Sean, agree. I intent to do bot programming, but don't want to disturb others, so I figure I'd better play within my own group first. So it's kind of related.